# sql database returns 0 for values that are present in database. searching URL

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table with urls to chess games. 
when i manually search for the url i get zero results. i literally use the phpmyadmin interface and i copy the link from within the table and run the query and i get zero results. What am i missing?

below is a link of a video demonstrating the problem
https://youtu.be/oGSp9YvJXRY

Answer (score 0):

You need to use single quotes to surround a string in SQL.

```
WHERE game_link = '<link_here>'
```

Anyways for further questions: Do NOT post them as video, just give the needed info as text. You could have just copied your `SELECT` statement in here...

Comment: my laptop crashed this morning but wow i hope it really is that simple. I believe i have tried single quotes and it didnt work. I apologise for posting the video i just thought it would be more elaborate than my text

Comment: i tried using single quotes it still returns zero. when i use strcmp method i get a value of 1. is there a way that i could find out what the difference between the two identical strings is? or atleast the index of where the difference occurs??